# Iterate through a list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to iterate through a list of lists in python. I print all the values first, then subsequent iterations, I delete the last value, for example:

```
mylists=[["near", "belle", "round", "about"],[" vue"," bus"," stop"],["sammy"],["mombasa","road"]]
```

In the above list, I print:

```
"near belle round about"
"near belle round"
"near belle"
"near"
```

and continue with all the other lists.

Kindly help me with the best way to do this, I have the following code which doesn't give me what I want.

```
for list in sentence:

    while len(list) >0:
        print list.pop()
```

Comment: Is this the correct data? You have the first sublist as `["near belle round about"]`, a `list` with a single `str` of all four words, but from your description, it seems like it should be `["near", "belle", "round", "about"]`, a `list` of four separate `str`, one per word.

Comment: Yes sorry i have edited the data

Comment: Do you need recursion? Or are you fine with any method?

Comment: should _for list in sentence:_ be _for list in mylists:_?

Comment: Yes it has to be myList. The term that follows "in" has to be your iterable i.e. list/array/dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the return from `pop`, but it sounds like you want what's left after the `pop`. Try this:

```
for alist in mylists:           # Use alist, not list, to avoid shadowing list built-in
    while alist:                 # Faster equivalent to while len(alist) > 0:
        print(' '.join(alist))   # Join and print current value
        alist.pop()              # Remove last, finished when emptied
```

Your question title asks about doing this recursively, but your attempt wasn't recursive, and which step you intend to be recursive is somewhat unclear; the problem doesn't require recursion at all.

Comment: Thank you very much!,made my day

Answer (score 0):

using a nested list comprehension:

```
[[' '.join(x[:i]) for i in range(len(x), 0, -1)] for x in mylists]
```

You could use print if you don't want the output:

```
[[print(' '.join(x[:i])) for i in range(len(x), 0, -1)] for x in mylists];
```

nb use `xrange` if using python 2

Answer (score -1):

```
for list in mylists:     #iterator for outer list
    while len(list) >0:  #iterator for inner list , length of inner list > 0
        print list       #print elements in the inner list 
        list.pop()       #pop the last element of the inner list
```

Comment: Where are you using recursion?

Comment: @Adib: I'm not sure the OP actually wants recursion in the CS  sense, I think they just mean they need to drill down into a nested structure.

Comment: I edited the post and removed the tags after OP's response provided that they don't care about recursion

Comment: you should add a little explanation as to what this code is doing